# Find the distribution of a variable from joint distribution law

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble with this particular problem.

> Let the random vector $(\xi, \eta)$ has the following joint distribution law
>   $p(1, 1) = 1/8$,  $p(2, 1) = 1/4$,  $p(1, 2) = 1/8$,  $p(2, 2) = 1/2$.
>
> Find the distribution of $\xi$, if $\eta = i$, $i = 1, 2$.

What does it mean by the distribution of $\xi$? Does this mean that I have to say that

> $p(\xi, 1) = 1/8 + 1/8 = 1/4$ and $p(\xi, 2) = 1/8 + 1/2 = 3/4$

I suspect that it has to do something with joint CDF, but I have no idea how to derive it from the data that I was given.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are being asked to find conditional probability.

For example,

$$P(\xi=1|\eta=1)=\frac{P(\xi=1,\eta=1)}{P(\eta=1)}$$ and $$P(\xi=2|\eta=1)=\frac{P(\xi=2,\eta=1)}{P(\eta=1)}$$